# Is it possible to make this ruby regex code shorter?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
regex = Regexp.new(/param\s*=\s*([^\|]*)/)
regex.match(text).to_s
link = $1
link.strip!
```

espesially code like this:

```
regex = Regexp.new(/regex/)
regex.match(text).to_s
match = $1
```

I even tried gsub misuse, but it is not The Right Way®

```
match = gsub Regexp.new(/.*(regex).*/, '\1')
```

Comment: Well, you can make the regex one character shorter: `/param\s*=\s*([^|]*)/`. But I don't know Ruby, so I can't tell what exactly that code does.

Comment: I try to extract data from String using regex but I am unable to do it in single line. And "[^|]" - | is special character - is it safe to ignore it?

Comment: Inside a character class, regex metacharacters don't have to be escaped (except possibly `[`, `]`, `-` and `^`, depending on their position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So given a string like this:

```
s = "blah blah param=pancakes|eggs"
```

You want to extract just `"pancakes"`, right? If so, then:

```
you_want = s[/param\s*=\s*([^|]+)/, 1]
```

The `\s*` will eat up any leading whitespace so half of your [`strip!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001196) is not needed. If you don't want any whitespace inside the extracted value at all then:

```
you_want = s[/param\s*=\s*([^|\s]+)/, 1]
```

If you just want to strip off the trailing whitespace, then add an [`rstrip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001191):

```
you_want = s[/param\s*=\s*([^|]*)/, 1].rstrip
```

This one will throw an exception if `s` doesn't your regular expression though.

See [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001128) for further details.

I've also changed your `[]*` to `[]+` to avoid matching nothing at all. Also, you don't have to escape most metacharacters inside a character class (see Tim's comment) so just `|` is fine inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

```
text =~ /param\s*=\s*([^|]*)/
match = $~[1]
```

gets the contents of the capturing group number 1 from your input string `text` into the variable `match`.

Comment: @mu: Thanks! See, I don't know Ruby :)